# How to call function by user input in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a mechanical button presser with a motor. I have written some code. I have some tasks given to press the button in different intervals (ex long press, short press, 3 sec press, etc)

```
from time import sleep    
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO    

DIR = 26   # Direction GPIO Pin    
STEP = 19  # Step GPIO Pin    
CW = 1     # Clockwise Rotation    
CCW = 0    # Counterclockwise Rotation    
SPR = 15   # Steps per Revolution (360 / 1.8)    

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)    
GPIO.setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT)    
GPIO.setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT)    
GPIO.output(DIR, CW)    

MODE = (14, 15, 18)   # Microstep Resolution GPIO Pins     
GPIO.setup(MODE, GPIO.OUT)    
RESOLUTION = {'Full': (0, 0, 0),    
              'Half': (1, 0, 0),    
              '1/4': (0, 1, 0),    
              '1/8': (1, 1, 0),    
              '1/16': (0, 0, 1),    
              '1/32': (1, 0, 1)}    

GPIO.output(MODE, RESOLUTION['Full'])    
step_count = SPR    
delay = .0208     

for x in range(step_count):    
    GPIO.output(DIR, CCW)    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)    
    sleep(delay)    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)    
    sleep(delay)    

sleep(2)    
GPIO.output(DIR, CW)    
for x in range(step_count):    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)    
    sleep(delay)    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)    
    sleep(delay)    

for x in range(step_count):    
    GPIO.output(DIR, CCW)    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)    
    sleep(delay)    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)    
    sleep(delay)

sleep(8)    
GPIO.output(DIR, CW)     
for x in range(step_count):    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)    
    sleep(delay)    
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)    
    sleep(delay)    
GPIO.cleanup()
```

In the above code you can see I have two intervals i.e 2 sec press and 8 sec press. So I want something when we run the code it will ask which function you want to use and then after giving input it will call that particular interval and the button will get pressed for that interval. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctly understand the context in which you want to ask for user input (since most RPs are used in environments where you can't easily get a command prompt in the first place).

But assuming that you do have some kind of shell in which you're running this Python script, this is one way:

```
def short_press():
    ...

def long_press():
    ...

actions = {'short': short_press, 'long': long_press}

command = input('Choose an action: ({})'.format(', '.join(actions.keys())))

if command in actions:
    actions[command]()
else:
    raise ValueError('{} is not a recognized action'.format(command)
```

Comment: I have tried to put the function in that def thing but it did not work